# How to find the TypeOf a VB6 control in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, com-interop, vb6-migration

I am writing a .NET DLL to iterate through all controls in the a VB6 Form passed byref.

So far it seems to work VB.NET code:

```
Public Sub AddFormRefLegacy(ByRef strAppName As String, ByRef objForm As Object)

        'update the forms caption
        objForm.Caption = FindValue(strAppName, objForm.Name, "", "0", objForm.Caption)

        'iterate through all the controls on the form          
        For Each ctl As Object In objForm.Controls
           if TypeOf ctl is Label then
             'this doesn't pick up any labels
           end if
        Next
    End Sub
```

Called from this VB6 code:

```
Dim libDD As New Lib.clsDataDictionary
libDD.AddFormRefLegacy "nnne", Me
```

but the TypeOf operator does not work. Is there another way to find the type of control?

Comment: You are comparing apples and oranges.  The VB.NET Label class is a .NET class, the VB6 Label control is an ActiveX control.  The only possible approach is Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject + Marshal.QueryInterface but the IIDs for these controls isn't obtainable anywhere that I know of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be you're comparing two different "Label" type objects.

You haven't qualified the LABEL type in the IF TYPEOF line, so you could be comparing a VB6 label to a .net label, and they wouldn't be the same.

You could use TYPENAME, but that might not be exactly what you need iether. I'd make sure you're really comparing the types that you think you're comparing.

Comment: Thanks for the point in the right direction- I appreciate I am comparing two different things but I wanted to find some way of finding the VB6 type. TypeName works well and I can code up a select statement to work with the variuous types. My function only deals with VB6 Forms and I have another one to deal with .NET ones so mixing the types is not an issue - thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the TypeName function? Does it return anything useful for TypeName(ctl)?

Comment: Yes TypeName returns "Label" "Frame" "CommandButton", etc so this works for me.